# If C'$_{ji}$ is a cofactor of C$^T$, how can I explain why C'$_{ji}$=C$_{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, formal-proofs

I am stuck with this proof. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Please bring the title down into the body. It's difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $ji$ cofactor of $C^T$ is the determinant of the matrix that arises from deleting the $j-th$ row and $i-th$ column of $C^T$, with the sign $(-1)^{i+j}$.  That's the same as deleting the $j-th$ column and $i-th$ row of $C$  So it's the $ij$ co-factor of $C$, since the sign won't change.